# Проблема с Kali Linux

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

У меня проблема с установкой дополнений для Kali Linux, она установлена на Virtual box, когда я нажимаю "подключить образ диска дополнений гостевой ОС" у меня монтируется диск с файлами для Windows, такими как "VBoxWindowsAdditions.exe", как я могу установить дополнения с файлами Linux? команду apt-get update && apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r) я уже пробовал, не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дык там на одном диске дистрибутивы для всех ОС сразу.
Копируете `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` как на скриншоте

[image: VBoxLinuxAdditions.run]

Открываете терминал, авторизуйтесь как пользователь правами root (команда `sudo su` или просто `su`).

Далее вставляете путь к файлу в терминал, и жмёте клавишу `Enter`. Если что-то спросит, со всем соглашайтесь. Потом виртуальную машину надо перезагрузить с новыми модулями ядра.

[image: Вставляем VBoxLinuxAdditions.run в терминал]